# How do you configure an Event Hub KEDA scaler for Azure Container Apps?

Tags: azure, azure-container-apps, keda, eventhub

I’ve been trying to configure an Azure Container App to have a custom scale rule using the `event-hub` KEDA scaler, and I haven't had any success.

I always hit this error:

> unable to get unprocessedEventCount for metrics: unable to get checkpoint from storage: %!w()

Unfortunately, the error doesn’t give much away about the problem it’s facing.

This is my scaler:

```
         {
            name: 'my-eh-keda-scaler'
            custom: {
              type: 'azure-eventhub'
              metadata: {
                connectionFromEnv: 'KEDA_EH_CONNECTION'
                storageConnectionFromEnv: 'KEDA_STORAGE_CONNECTION'
                consumerGroup: 'my-consumer-group'
                unprocessedEventThreshold: '64'
                blobContainer: 'my-container'
                checkpointStrategy: 'blobMetadata'
                activationUnprocessedEventThreshold: '1'
              }
            }
          }
```

The referenced connection string in the environment variable works and has full access. The event hub connection string also works and has full access.

I’ve followed the documentation here: *[Azure Event Hubs](https://keda.sh/docs/2.11/scalers/azure-event-hub/)*

How can I fix this or alternatively is there an example that works?

Comment: Is "scaler" an official term?

Comment: They’re called KEDA scalers, yea. https://keda.sh/docs/2.13/scalers/